# All the records in is not getting fetched from BIM360 through Data Management API in Power Automate

Tags: autodesk-forge, power-automate, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

We are fetching file name from the folders in BIM360 using power automate. We have an excel file in one drive and we want to update the date and version number for the file name mentioned in the excel file and this is based on the file that is uploaded in BIM360. The flow is we read the files in all folders and filter it based on the file name mentioned in the excel file. If the file mentioned in the excel file is present in bim360 then we extract the updated date and version number and then add it in respective columns in the excel file.

Only for few file names we are getting the updated date and version number. For some files it is not getting updated even when the file is present in the BIM360.

Let me know if any of you can help me in this. Will share more information if required.

Thank you

We tried changing the flow and condition but still it is not helping. No matter what we try all the file name from the bim360 is not getting fetched. Only few are being fetched properly.

Comment: Hi Aneesha, did you ask a similar question via Autodesk product support? The issue you addressed looks like an existing support case no. 19718257. Before jumping into this issue, I would like to confirm with you to avoid duplicate efforts since one of my colleagues is helping you.

Comment: If that's not you, could you point out which API you calls in the PowerAutomate, since PowerAutomate is a 3rd-party tool, not from APS(formerly Forge)?

Comment: Hi Eason, We were able to find out the issue. It is not from Autodesk. It is in the flow created in power-automate. We are working on changing the flow. Thank you for the response.

Comment: NP, Happy to hear you found the issue. :)